# Why is useState<string>() not a TypeScript error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

This is ok:

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState<string>()
```

This is not:

```
const [boo, setBoo] = useState<string>(undefined)
```

> Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | (() => string)'

I think they have the same meaning, though - `useState` with no arguments is the same as `useState(undefined)`.

Is it simply that TypeScript can't detect this for some reason?

Comment: Because the no-args and one-arg forms are different, they the initialValue is undefined isn't relevant: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/22748370e3a302492e98a7d42ee28b65551292fc/types/react/index.d.ts#L927-L941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the [DefinitelyTyped definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ba2bb0f778c0973b66264c4bf0eed3aa95169efc/types/react/index.d.ts#L916) is overloaded with 2 signatures for `useState`, where one of them has no arguments:

```js
// with argument
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
// no argument
function useState<S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S | undefined>>];
```

If you want the argument definition to allow for an `undefined` you need to explicitly define it like so:

```js
const [boo, setBoo] = useState<string|undefined>(undefined)
```

Answer (score 3):

`useState<string>()` is a convinence shorthand for `useState<string|undefined>(undefined)`

The typing is [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L941)

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
// convenience overload when first argument is omitted
// ...
function useState<S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S | undefined>>];
```

As stated in the code comment, this is just convinience, not an omission but put there on purpose.

Do not use this is your state must strictly be a `string` as  omiting the argument makes `undefined` to also be allowed.

Sidepoint: this also allows `useState()` with no argument or type argument, which results in a state object that can only be `undefined`